# How to find the directory path of a file in powershell

Tags: powershell

Let me tell about my scenario.

I have a file on the desktop, I don't know its full name  and where is it location. I just know that file starts with "ABC" and its an .exe. So I am trying to find the path to this file with the help of a script. I've tried to use this function.

```
  function  findPath ($path) {

return $thePath = Get-ChildItem -Path $path -Filter '*ABC*.exe'  -Recurse | % { $_.FullName }

}
```

When I call the this function this fun  gives me a string  input like:

```
    C:\Users\UserX\Desktop\New Folder\FolderA\FolderB\1_Abc.exe
```

Is there anyway to reach path of :

```
      C:\Users\UserX\Desktop\New Folder\FolderA\FolderB\
```

Comment: You can use .NET's `System.IO.Path`. `[System.IO.Path]::GetDirectoryName("C:\Path\To\File.txt")`

Comment: `$_.DirectoryName` would give you the path without filename

Comment: If you have a file on the Desktop, you know where it is located. What is your input for `$path`? **PowerShell** functions don't need [`Return`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_return?view=powershell-7.2). Are you actually looking for the folder that contains the *target of a shortcut*?

Answer (score 0):

`Split-Path -Path`  works for me.

Answer (score 0):

Guessing that you might be looking for the folder path of the target of a shortcut to an exxecutable. If so:

```
Function Get-TargetFolderPath ($LinkPath) {
    (new-object -com wscript.shell).CreateShortcut($Path).TargetPath | Split-Path
}
```

And, exclusively for Desktop shortcuts and URLS, this requires only the Dispaly Name of the the shortcut and works for items from both the user's Desktop folder and the Public Desktop folder:

```
Function Get-DesktopShortcutTargetPath ($LinkName) {
    (@((New-Object -com shell.application).NameSpace(0).Items()) | ? Name -eq $LinkName).ExtendedProperty("System.Link.TargetParsingPath") | Split-Path
}
```

```
PS > Function Get-DesktopShortcutTargetPath ($LinkName) {
>>     (@((New-Object -com shell.application).NameSpace(0).Items()) | ? Name -eq $LinkName).ExtendedProperty("System.Link.TargetParsingPath") | Split-Path
>> }
PS >
PS > Get-DesktopShortcutTargetPath 'Adobe Acrobat DC'
C:\Program Files\Adobe\Acrobat DC\Acrobat
```